# Выбрать из массива данных несколько рандомных значений в виде картинок

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, нужно выбрать из массива данных несколько рандомных значений и вывести их в виде картинок

Как привязать к каждому значению в массиве или словаре  картинку и потом вывести в "пикчербоксы"?

Вот так получилось выводить рандомную картинку по нажатию кнопки.

```cs
string[] food = new string[] { "Donut", "bread", "water" };

string randomfood = food[new Random().Next(0, Champ.Length)];

textBox2.Text = randomfood;

if (randomChamp == "Donut")
{
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.Donut_0;

}

if (randomChamp == "bread")
{
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.bread_0;

}

if (randomChamp == "water")
{
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.water_0;
```

Comment: Если вы можете выбрать одну картинку, в чем проблема выбрать несколько?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно будет в ресурсах назвать свои картинки именно так как они названы в массиве ключей food

```
string[] food = new string[] { "Donut", "bread", "water" };
string randomfood = food[new Random().Next(0, Champ.Length)]; 
pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(randomfood)
```

Comment: Спасибо это помогло)

Comment: @Alcatraz Отлично. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа :-)